# Suppress Numbering of Subfigures

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

Is there a way to supress the numberings of subfigures within subfigures?

Currently, I have something like the following:

```
\begin{figure}
  \subfigure{
    \subfigure{...}
    \subfigure{...}
    \subfigure{...}
  }
  \subfigure {
     ...
  }
  ...
\end{figure}
```

So I have the entire figure, within which I have subfigures, which consist of more figures (i.e. subsubfigures). Each subfigure contains 9 subsubfigures and I have 5 subfigures. Because each subsubfigure and each subfigure get numbered and labeled, I get a `Counter too large` error because there are more than a-z figures.

I only really care about the numbering and labeling on the subfigures (i.e. I don't care about the numbering on the subsubfigures). Is there a way to suppress the numbering on the subsubfigures so that I only have subfigures a through e that are labeled and thus also avoid the error?

Comment: You didn't mention which package you're using to get subfigures. Which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't need labels and numbers of subsubfigures, and I guess you don't need captions as well, you could simply use `minipage` environments or `\parbox` for those figures instead of nesting subfigures.

Further, if you use the [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package, which is outdated, you might consider to use the newer [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) package instead.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution with the already mentioned »subcaption« package (shipped with [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon}

\title{Two subfigures without a caption}
\author{Myx}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  \blindtext

  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Dummy figures}\label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}

  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't use `\caption` inside the `subfigure` environments, you don't need `subfigure` environments (and therefore the subcaption package) at all. Just use `minipage`s instead.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to suppress numbering in captions is to use `\caption*{}` instead of `\caption{}`. This works in figures and in subfigures also.