# Nested subfloats with detailed caption control

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I have four images, each with a corresponding magnified version of a small portion of it. I would like to arrange them so that the zoomed out versions are on one row side by side, and the corresponding zoomed versions are under them on a second row.

Then, I'd like there to only be subfloat caption numbers (a,b,c...) under the lower row so that `a` refers to both the full view and zoomed view.

I tried modifying Thorsten Donig's example from here: [Suppress Numbering of Subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6841/suppress-numbering-of-subfigures), with the result being the code below which DOES DO what I want.

So, my question is, is my approach a smart way to do what I want, or is there a better way to get the effect of nested subfigs with granular caption control?

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title{Two subfigures without a caption}
\author{Myx}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \blindtext

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty} % Turn off label display. Label counter keep counting silently
    % First row of figures (with no labels)
    \subfloat[]{
        \subfloat[]{
            \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
        }
        \hspace{10pt}
        \subfloat[]{
            \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
        }
    }

    % Second row of figures (with labels)
    \subfloat[]{
    \setcounter{subfigure}{0} % Reset label counter so next subfig starts at `a`
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=default} % Turn label display back on
    \subfloat[]{
        \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    }
    \hspace{10pt}
    \subfloat[]{
        \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    }
    }

  \caption[Nested Subfloats]{Top row should have no captions, bottom row should start caption number at 'a'. }
  \label{fig.nested}
\end{figure}


  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `subcaption` package instead of `subfig` (the reason can be found in [subcaption vs. subfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/3954)). Since only the bottom row will receive captions, there's is no need to place the top row inside `subfigure` environments, and `minipage`s can be used to achiev the desired alignment. One possible way to achieve what you want using `subcaption` is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
  \end{minipage}\\[2em]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:sub3}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:sub4}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{A figure with four subfigures}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I would use `subfig` and its `\subfloat` macro is to get sub-figure captions. So why use it at all if you don't want them? You are not forced to wrap all your *images* inside a `figure` inside `\subfloat`. Just place the `\includegraphics` (or other) macros in it. If you want to align them in a special way with the the other images which have captions you could place them into a `minipage`s. Alternatively you can stack *two* images inside *one* `\subfloat` so they only get one caption. There is no rule which stops you from putting more than one image or other code into a `\subfloat` or main float.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title{Two subfigures without a caption}
\author{Myx}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \blindtext

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    % First row of images (with no labels)
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}%
    \hspace{10pt}%
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}%

    % Second row of images (with labels)
    \subfloat[]{%
        \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}%
    }%
    \hspace{10pt}%
    \subfloat[]{%
        \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}%
    }%

  \captionof{figure}[Nested Subfloats]{Top row should have no captions, bottom row should start caption number at 'a'. }
  \label{fig.nested}
\end{figure}


  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to label only columns, right? Then I would suggest the following.

Arrange your figures using subfloat and reset the counter before  adding the
captions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\clearsubcaptcounter}{\setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
  \hspace{1em}
  \subfloat{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}\\
  \clearsubcaptcounter
  \subfloat[Column 1]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
  \hspace{1em}
  \subfloat[Column 2]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The command \clearsubcaptioncounter resets the labeling of the captions.